# Console Log objects when using console.info.bind(console)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, console.log

I have seen many Angular2+ developers use the `console.info.bind(console)` method to make a logger service out of the javascript console logger. However, in my implementation of this, all of my javascript objects are logged out as `[object object]`.

How can I tweak my logger so that my objects are rendered in my console?

ConsoleLogger.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

import {Logger} from './logger.service';

export let isDebugMode = environment.isDebugMode;

const noop = (): any => undefined;

@Injectable()
export class ConsoleLoggerService implements Logger {
  get info() {
    if (isDebugMode) {
      return console.info.bind(console);
    } else {
      return noop;
    }
  }

  get warn() {
    if (isDebugMode) {
      return console.warn.bind(console);
    } else {
      return noop;
    }
  }
}
```

Logger.Service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

export abstract class Logger {
  info: any;
  warn: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class LoggerService implements Logger {
  info: any;
  warn: any;
}
```

Example.Component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoggerService} from 'src/app/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-component',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
  styles: ['example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  exampleObject: {a: 'apple'; b: 'banana'};
  constructor(
    private _logger: LoggerService,
  ) {
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
   this._logger.info("Example Output: " + this.exampleObject);
   // Example Output: [object object]
   // ?? i want to see the actual object
  }
}
```

Comment: String concatenation with `"Example Output: "` will always stringify the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the Object in console, you  should use JSON.stringify()

```
 return console.info.bind(JSON.stringify(console));
```

Comment: I just tried this and the behavior is the same. I'm still seeing [object object] in my console.

Comment: did you try  this._logger.info("Example Output: " + JSON.stringy(this.exampleObject));

Comment: Okay, that did work somewhat. It gave me a string of the object in my console. I'd rather not have to do that for every time i log something though. Also, the object is now a string in my console.. i'd rather it be an actual Object so i can more easily see it's contents.

Comment: if you want to see it contents use dot operator. console.someproperty

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this for awhile. I found out this gave me what I want.

```
this._logger.info('Example: ', this.exampleObject);
```